# AG-Grid Throwing Invalid Aria Property with React 17

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm exploring AG Grid and like what I see in the demo apps and my little demos. Am am doing a small POC integration with our application, and I started to receive a javascript error from React-DOM with an "Invalid aria prop".

```
react-dom.development.js:61 Warning: Invalid aria prop `aria-description` on <div> tag. For details, see https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-aria-props
    at div
    at HeaderCellComp (http://localhost:3000/redacted/static/js/bundle.js:110424:25)
    at div
    at HeaderRowComp (http://localhost:3000/redacted/static/js/bundle.js:110869:36)
    at div
    at div
    at HeaderRowContainerComp (http://localhost:3000/redacted/static/js/bundle.js:111018:20)
    at div
    at GridHeaderComp (http://localhost:3000/redacted/static/js/bundle.js:110335:20)
    at div
    at GridBodyComp (http://localhost:3000/redacted/static/js/bundle.js:109884:20)
    at TabGuardCompRef (http://localhost:3000/redacted/static/js/bundle.js:111683:24)
    at div
    at div
    at GridComp (http://localhost:3000/redacted/static/js/bundle.js:110118:20)
    at div
    at AgGridReactUi (http://localhost:3000/redacted/static/js/bundle.js:108709:24)
    at AgGridReact (http://localhost:3000/redacted/static/js/bundle.js:108170:43)
```

We are using React 17.0.2.

After looking into this, React 17.0.2 doesn't recognize "aria-description" as a valid aria property and it has only been fixed in React v18 (https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21035 and https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/22142). It appears that Facebook is concerned with misspelling attributes, so they have chosen to added an explicit check.

If AG Grid v29 is compatible with React 17 (`"peerDependencies": { "ag-grid-community": "~29.0.0", "react": "^16.3.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0", "react-dom": "^16.3.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" }`), Is anyone from AG Grid aware of this javascript error?

Does anyone know who to resolve this, other than the obvious of upgrading to React 18?

Searching for options, without upgrading the React version.

Answer (score 1):

Besides upgrading to React 18, you can downgrade to AgGrid 27.2. [AG Grid bug report](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/5211)